# beautiful soup to grab forex prices

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to using `beautiful soup` and I have been following tutorials on scraping with it. I am trying to use it to return high and low prices from common forex pairs. Im not sure if it is the sites that I'm trying to get the information rom, but I can find the `div tag` that I want the info from, I believe the text is hidden in the span, but i am still having trouble with it coming back `nonetype`.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

url : https://www.centralcharts.com/en/6748-aud-nzd/quotes

div class="tabMini-wrapper"

this is the whole table ^^ div class..

Is it because of the format the site has it in?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL = "https://www.centralcharts.com/en/6748-aud-nzd/quotes"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

spans=soup.find('span', attrs = {'class' , 'tabMini tabQuotes'})
print(spans)
```

I tried a bunch of different ways but this was most recent attempt. I was trying to get it from the span after the `.find()` returned `nonetype` for the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATED ANSWER 11-25-2022

Sorry for the slow reply I was away from my computer for the American holiday. Here is another way to accomplish your task. This one uses multiple list comprehensions and the zip to iterator over the data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.centralcharts.com/en/6748-aud-nzd/quotes"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


results = []
table_data = soup.select_one('h2:-soup-contains("5 days quotes")').find_next('table')
dates = [element.get('data-date') for element in table_data.find_all('span', attrs={'set-locale-date'})]
daily_high_quotes = [element.text for element in table_data.find('td', text='High').find_next_siblings('td')]
daily_low_quotes = [element.text for element in table_data.find('td', text='Low').find_next_siblings('td')]
for quote_date, daily_high, daily_low in zip(dates, daily_high_quotes, daily_low_quotes):
    results.append([quote_date, daily_high, daily_low])
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[['2022-11-21', '1.0854', '1.0811'], 
['2022-11-22', '1.0837', '1.0782'], 
['2022-11-23', '1.0837', '1.0746'], 
['2022-11-24', '1.0814', '1.0765'], 
['2022-11-25', '1.0822', '1.0796']]
```

### ORIGINAL ANSWER 11-24-2022

There are multiple tables on the pages, so you need to extract the data from the correct table. This code will help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.centralcharts.com/en/6748-aud-nzd/quotes"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for tag_element in soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class', 'tabMini tabQuotes'}):
    for item in tag_element.find_all('td'):
        print(item)
```

Comment: High 1.1001 1.0993 1.0981 1.0915 1.0812
Low 1.0948 1.0944 1.0894 1.0834

Comment: it didnt allow me to paste the snippet.. there are two rows in the table HIGH and LOW.. and i want to be able to capture the entire row ( which is a 5 day period)

Comment: this is good i see its grabbing the entire table.. ive tried to limit it down to just the td of high and low .. the two rows in the table..  i tried being more specific when using the findall instead of just finding td .. i tried finding the "high:" td but its not coming back with anything

Comment: I’m not near my computer for the holiday at the moment.  I will look at this later today.

Answer (score 2):

Oke, **Version 2**..

---

It seems like OP want to capture the [complete table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtd58.png), with date.

Since this is an HTML table, you'll need to make a custom loop that will map both the headers (`th`) and rows (`tr > td`)

---

steps the script takes:

1. Find the `table`
2. For each header, append the `data-date` to the `result` object
3. Find all the `tr`'s in the table
4. Index 5 is high, index 6 is low (this could be improved by searching for the text)
5. Ensure `high` and `low` have the same amount of items
6. Map the index of the row with the index of the header, append to `result` (could probably be improved using something like `zip()`

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

result = []

URL = "https://www.centralcharts.com/en/6748-aud-nzd/quotes"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

table = soup.select('.prod-left-content .tabMini-wrapper table')[0]

for header in table.find('thead').find_all('span', attrs = { 'class': 'set-locale-date' }):
    result.append({ 'date': header.get('data-date'), 'high': None, 'low': None })

trs = table.select('tbody > tr')

high = trs[5].find_all('span')
low  = trs[6].find_all('span')

if (len(high) != len(low)):
    print('Mmmm, somehting went wrong?')
    exit()

for i in range(len(high)):
    result[i]['low'] = low[i].text
    result[i]['high'] = high[i].text

for o in result:
    print(o['date'] + "\t\t" + o['high'] + "\t" + o['low'])
```

Gives:

```
2022-11-18      1.0915  1.0834
2022-11-21      1.0854  1.0811
2022-11-22      1.0837  1.0782
2022-11-23      1.0837  1.0746
2022-11-24      1.0812  1.0765
```

Comment: first off thank you for the response .. wow. ok well thats a great start.how would i manipulate this to grab all of the highs and lows.. it only shows them for a 5 day period on the table.. i see the td for high has all the prices listed in the High td that its finding are they already scraped and i need to call them up to print them?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot where you highlight the data you want to capture from that site?

Comment: the orange text are classes correct? Is it only grabbing the numbers you showed because those have a class with them? the entire row of high and low are listed there in that td of high and low... i just dont know why its only selected to grab that newest one

Comment: Orange text? you mean `print` in code? Thats a python function

Comment: no no sorry in the inspection view while viewing the code

Comment: I dont understand you

Comment: the one its grabbing has  '47127cot-update-quote-high' in front of it in orange text even though they are all under the same td of High or Low .. is this the reason its only grabbing that single price? i wish i could share a picture on here

Comment: i sent you an email so i could attach the snippet

Comment: PLease see v2 of my answer. Took a bit more then expected. Hope this helps